# Divisiblity of $n$ with $a,b,c$ is relative prime to p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given an arbitrary prime $p > 2011$. Prove that there exist positive integers $a,b,c$ such that there exists some numbers from $a, b, c$ that are relatively prime to $p$, and for all positive integers $n$ such that $p|n^4 − 2n^2 + 9$, $p$ divides $24an^2 + 5bn + 2011c$.

I have no idea for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $a,b,c$ such that:
$p| 24a-1 ; p| 5b+2; p|2011c-9$

Comment: but can you make sure that there will be such prime number that you say?? @ToanNguyenDinh

Comment: Hm, as $ p>2011$, hence $ gcd(24,p)=gcd(5,p)=gcd(2011,c)=1$. Then due to Chinese Remainder Theorem,  there are such numbers . After that, due to $gcd(1,p)=gcd(2,p)=gcd(9,p)$; $gcd(a,p)=gcd(b,p)=gcd(c,p)=1$